# What happened when you don't write back HTTP cookie to client?

Tags: http, go, browser, protocols, session-cookies

What happened when you don't write back cookie?
I'm using [fasthttp](https://github.com/valyala/fasthttp), would the previously sent cookie from the server deleted on the browser if you don't write back a cookie?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What happened when you don't write back cookie?

Then the cookie doesn't change. The name stays the same. The value stays the same. The rules for when it expires stay the same.

> would the previously sent cookie from the server deleted on the browser if you don't write back a cookie?

No.